# UITextView crashed,when @font-face refrence ttf file is missing

Tags: css, crash, uitextview, font-face

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlcpz.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Unknown</title>
  <link href="file:///var/mobile/Applications/E450E9B5-A298-4912-BF3F-FBDE9D655B34/Library/Caches/UnzippedEpub/812CDAD1-30BF-454D-A3AD-6C24E06DEED8/OEBPS/Styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    @page {
      margin-bottom: 5.000000pt;
      margin-top: 5.000000pt;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: "21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84";
      src: local(serif)
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: "21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84";
      src: url(res:///Data/FONT/tt0003m_.ttf)
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: "21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84";
      src: url(../Fonts/21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84.ttf)
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="calibre">
  <h1 class="title" id="calibre_pb_0">book title</h1>
  <div class="annotation">
    author
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to display the local html code using UITextView,but I find that if the .ttf file is missing(or the file path is invalid),the UITextView crash.
if i edit the @font-face like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: "21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84"; src:local("21bdaaa95f669f5452de0c164082dc84.ttf") }
```

every thing is very well.
I would like to know how to avoid the UITextView crash without modifying the HTML
(sorry about my english!)